# SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, dbeaver

Quando adiciono uma nova linha na tabela eu consigo deletar usando o comando:

`DELETE
FROM
    ebdb.tb_categoria as tc
WHERE
    id = 790;`

Porém, as linhas que já existem não consigo deletar e retorna o erro:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as tc
>   WHERE
>       id = 790' at line 3

Acho estranho, pois, alterações como UPDATE eu consigo executar nestas linhas. Estou usando o DBeaver 6.2.2

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: sua tabela deve estar relacionada com outra, e está excluindo um registro da qual a outra depende

Comment: Tire este "as tc"

Comment: realmente o item desta tabela estava relacionado com outra tabela. obrigada :)